# how to make column responsive on small screen html css only

Tags: html, css

I want these columns responsive if the screen size is small i want them to break downwards and adjust width 100% on small screen.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count:2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    text-align:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-count property.</p>

<div class="newspaper">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in css.

```css
.newspaper {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  text-align: left;
}


/* max-width value depend on at which resolution you need text in single column, As for now to achieve that in mobile I have used 767px */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .newspaper {
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-count property.</p>

<div class="newspaper">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
  ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue
  duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px)
    {
        .newspaper {
            -webkit-column-count:1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -moz-column-count: 1; /* Firefox */
            column-count: 1;
        }
    }
```